# How to implement an n-gram inverted index from a paper (Python)?

Tags: python, indexing, string-matching, n-gram, inverted-index

I am trying to implement an **n-Gram/2L-approximation index** from a paper by Min-Soo Kim, Kyu-Young Whang and Jae-Gil Lee, found here: [http://infolab.dgist.ac.kr/~mskim/papers/CSSE07.pdf](http://infolab.dgist.ac.kr/%7Emskim/papers/CSSE07.pdf)

Building the Index is quite straight forward. Where I am getting lost is the querying algorithm.
Specifically performing the *merge outer join*.

> The algorithm extracts n-grams from the query string
> Q by the 1-sliding technique and searches the posting lists
> of those n-grams in the front-end index. Then, the algorithm performs merge outer join among those posting lists
> using the m-subsequence identifier as the join attribute and
> finds the set {Si} of candidate m-subsequences that satisfy
> the necessary condition in Theorem 1.

So far, I got this piece of code:

```py
from math import ceil, floor

class NGramIndex:
    def __init__(self, m: int, n: int):
        self.m: int = m  # m-subsequence length
        self.n: int = n  # n-gram length
        self.backend_index = dict()
        self.frontend_index = dict()
        self.msubseq_set = []  # Set of msubsequences
        
    def append(self, doc: str, doc_id: int):
        N = len(doc)
        
        max_range = ceil(N / self.m)
        for i in range(0, max_range):
            offset = i * self.m
        
            msubseq = doc[i * self.m: i * self.m + self.m]
            # if extracted subseq is smaller, pad it with extra-char
            if len(msubseq) < self.m:
                msubseq += '$' * (self.m - len(msubseq))
            
            if msubseq not in self.backend_index:
                self.backend_index[msubseq] = [(doc_id, [offset])]
            elif self.backend_index[msubseq][-1][0] == doc_id:
                self.backend_index[msubseq][-1][1].append(offset)
            else:
                self.backend_index[msubseq].append((doc_id, [offset]))
                
            if msubseq in self.msubseq_set:
                # subseq_id is the unique identifier in msubseq_set
                subseq_id = self.msubseq_set.index(msubseq)
            else:
                self.msubseq_set.append(msubseq)
                subseq_id = len(self.msubseq_set) - 1
                max_q_range = self.m - self.n + 1

                for ngram_offset in range(0, max_q_range):
                    ngram = msubseq[ngram_offset:ngram_offset + self.n]
                    if ngram not in self.frontend_index:
                        self.frontend_index[ngram] = [(subseq_id, [ngram_offset])]
                    elif self.frontend_index[ngram][-1][0] == subseq_id:
                        self.frontend_index[ngram][-1][1].append(ngram_offset)
                    else:
                        self.frontend_index[ngram].append((subseq_id, [ngram_offset]))
                        
    def query(self, query_word: str, k: int):
        """
        Query the index for results
        k = error tolerance (threshold)
        
        """
        t = floor((len(query_word) + 1) / self.m) - 1
        eps = floor(k / t)
        # r is used for filtration later
        r = (self.m - self.n + 1) - (eps * self.n)
        
        postings = []
        
        for i in range(0, len(query_word) - self.n + 1):
            ngram = query_word[i: i + self.n]
            if ngram in self.frontend_index:
                postings.append(self.frontend_index[ngram])
        
        # TODO: Perform merge outer join?
```

and I am unsure how to proceed with the join.

I am glad for any suggestions, references, anything.

Comment: Is the paper not a perfect reference?